# RGB colours in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a set of points stored in a giant string, with newline characters \n separating one point from the next. Each point is stored as x y z r g b, where r g b are values ranging from 0-255.

According to the ThreeJS docs, it is possible to do this:

```
var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(255,0,0)");
```

However, my points still show up as all white in my ThreeJS viewer. What am I doing wrong?
Code is as follows:

```
var cloud = data.split('\n');

for (var i=0; i<cloud.length; i++) {
    var colour = 'rgb(' + pt[3] + ',' + pt[4] + ',' + pt[5] + ')';
    model.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z) );
    colours.push( new THREE.Color(colour) );
}
```

Comment: How do you get data `pt[3]` to `pt[5]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised what my mistake was: I forgot to parse points 3 to 5 as floats.

This fixed it:

```
var colour = 'rgb(' + parseFloat(pt[3]) + ',' + parseFloat(pt[4]) + ',' + parseFloat(pt[5]) + ')';
```